# Validation data shall be in broken down into batches or not?

Tags: training

I am using `fit_generator` to train the model. The training dataset is being read from a generator function which gives data in a constant batch size. Now I want to know what approach shall I adopt for validation data. Shall I make a generator for the validation set or load it completely into memory and use it in `fit_generator`?

Note: Validation dataset is fitting into memory quite easily therefore batching is an option for me.

Answer (score 0):

If `validation batch size = 1` it has no difference in comparison with the case that load the data completely. But with any other value of `batch size` the evaluation metric will be an average of it in different batches; So, its real value will not be resulted.